# the function form.validate_on_submit() is always returning false even if the form input is correct , I just started with flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

in the route code I printed the form.validate_on_submit() output, It always comes out to be false and renders the index.html file

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form=RegistrationForm()
    print(form.validate_on_submit())
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return "validation successfull"
    else:
        return render_template('index.html',form=form)
```

here's the form class, all the impportant keywords are instantiated in the original file

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username=StringField('Username',validators=[
            DataRequired(message='Username required'),
            Length(min=4,max=25,message='Username must be 4 to 25 characters long')
            ])
    password=PasswordField('Password',validators=[
            DataRequired(message='Password required'),
            Length(min=4,message='Password must be more than 4 characters long')
            ])
    confirm_pswd=PasswordField('Confirm Password',validators=[
            DataRequired(message='Password required'),
            EqualTo('password',message='Password must Match')
            ])
    submit=SubmitField('Submit')
```

here's the index.html file complete code
I've used jinja templating and displayed the form that is passed in the route

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block title %} Registration {% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>GetStarted</h1>
    <form action="{{url_for('index')}}" method="POST">
        <div>
            {{form.username.label(class='form-control-label')}}
            {{form.username( class = 'form-control',
                placeholder = 'Username',
                autofocus = true)}}

                {% if form.username.errors %}
                    <div>    
                        {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                        <p><small>{{error}}</small></p>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{form.password.label(class='form-control-label')}}
            {{form.password( class = 'form-control',
                placeholder = 'Password')}}

                {% if form.password.errors %}
                    <div>    
                        {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                        <p><small>{{error}}</small></p>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{form.confirm_pswd.label(class='form-control-label')}}
            {{form.confirm_pswd( class = 'form-control',
                placeholder = 'Retype Password')}}

                {% if form.confirm_pswd.errors %}
                    <div>    
                        {% for error in form.confirm_pswd.errors %}
                        <p><small>{{error}}</small></p>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{form.submit}}
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You are missing the CSRF token in your form. See the docs here: https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/csrf/#html-forms

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg Thank you for your input , I used CSRF token and made a few modifications . It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You need add:

`<form action="{{url_for('index')}}" method="POST">`

`{{ form.hidden_tag() and form.csrf_token }}`